# Query JSON where namespace and pod names are on the same level to output list of 'namespaces[].pods[].containers'

Tags: json, jq

Taking the sample input JSON below, I am attempting to output a list of `namespaces[].pods[].containers`. An example of my desired output can be found below.

Using the existing query below, I can get to `.pods[].containers`, but as the `namespace` is included in the metadata which is at the same level as the pod name, I'm unsure as to how I can achieve my desired structure.

How can I modify the query to get my desired output?

Just in case it is of any use - the structure of the sample input is a trimmed down version of the output of `kubectl get pods -A -o json`. I removed the properties I'm not interested in.

#### Existing query

```
.items | { namespaceCount: ([ .[].metadata.namespace ] | unique | length), podCount: (. | length), containerCount: ([ .[].spec.containers[].image ] | length), pods: [ .[] | { name: .metadata.name, namespace: .metadata.namespace, containers: [ .spec.containers[] | { name, image } ] } ] }
```

#### Sample input JSON

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "pod-in-namespace-1-a",
                "namespace": "namespace-1"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "image": "some/image:1.2.3",
                        "name": "container1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "pod-in-namespace-1-b",
                "namespace": "namespace-1"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "image": "another/image:9.8.7",
                        "name": "container2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Output from existing query

```
{
  "namespaceCount": 1,
  "podCount": 2,
  "containerCount": 2,
  "pods": [
    {
      "name": "pod-in-namespace-1-a",
      "namespace": "namespace-1",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "container1",
          "image": "some/image:1.2.3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pod-in-namespace-1-b",
      "namespace": "namespace-1",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "container2",
          "image": "another/image:9.8.7"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Desired output

```
{
  "namespaceCount": 1,
  "podCount": 2,
  "containerCount": 2,
  "namespaces": [
    {
      "name": "namespace-1",
      "pods": [
        {
          "name": "pod-in-namespace-1-a",
          "containers": [
            {
              "name": "container1",
              "image": "some/image:1.2.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "pod-in-namespace-1-b",
          "containers": [
            {
              "name": "container2",
              "image": "another/image:9.8.7"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're describing is that each pod says what namespace it's in, there can be multiple different namespaces (not shown in your example) and you want to group them up by namespace. You can use the [`group_by`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#group_by(path_expression)) function.

Try:

```
.items |
{
    namespaceCount: ([ .[].metadata.namespace ] | unique | length),
    podCount: (. | length),
    containerCount: ([ .[].spec.containers[].image ] | length),
    namespaces: [
        group_by(.metadata.namespace)[]|
        {
            name: .[0].metadata.namespace,
            pods: [
                .[] |
                {
                    name: .metadata.name,
                    containers: [ .spec.containers[] | { name, image } ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, `group_by()` seems to be the magic that I was trying to find.
Note however that the assumption about pods being in multiple different namespaces is incorrect, but no matter as the query still works as I'd like. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that a single pod can belong to more than one namespace, merely that you expect more than one namespace in total.